# how to format the date returned by mongodb in node.js [ data is in array ]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and by using

```
objmodel.find(query, function(err,result){        
callbackvalue(err,result);
});
```

prototype of code.

that result object contains array of json like

```
{
  "feild1":"",
  "datefield" :"",
  "field":[ 
    {
     "datefield":""
     "field2":""
 }
```

This is the sample of one document in the result.

i need to change the date format to IST format
and again need to show the same json array in the browser.

what is the best way to achieve it ?

I put a loop and changed everything in the result object.
in mongodb actually 5 hrs 30 mins is lagging
but the same field while 
making console.log(field) in node.js it is giving correct.
But i want the same in the json and it has to be send as result to the response as json.

Answer (score 0):

To change you schema output, use the transform Option in the toObject method like this :

```
mymodel.toObject({ transform : function(model, modelObject, options){
    _.each(modelObject.field, function(field, index){
        modelObject.field[index].datefield = "yourconverteddate field.datefield";
    });         

}});
```